# Android wont let me compile NinePatch file - file.9.png

Tags: android, nine-patch

What is the extension for 9 patch files?   xxxxx.9.png?
Thats what is being explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

"It must be saved with the extension .9.png, and saved into the res/drawable/ directory of your project. "

But when im trying to compile the project i get error - because of the file name! i cant hold 2 dots in the filename..

So how do i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SDK directory, there is a tool called "draw9patch"

> /path/to/sdk/tools/draw9patch

You have to use that to create your Nine-patch images. You cannot just rename any image with the .9.png extension. When the image has been properly formatted with the tool, you will no longer get the compilation errors.

Read about how to use the tool here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: Yes i've done it using the 9-patch tool, and saved the files using the tool, as explained!

Comment: I've entered to the 9-patch tool again, and saved only one file of button, and now it seems to work..
I Guess something messed up on one of the files that corrupted them..  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NinePatch files have the extension '.9.png'

Some filenames that have Java keywords will cause issues (e.g. try having a resource named **private**).

Other than that I suggest you clean your project.

Comment: I've cleaned up my project, and renamed a few times the file names, and it still doesnt work!